# Make a server listen to a specific port or Flask app running on another?

Tags: python, flask, port, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

#### Versiones

rasa-core :               0.9.0a3
rasa-nlu  :               0.12.3

#### Problema

I have a [web-app chat and a Rasa server](https://github.com/antoinecomp/myflaskapp/tree/master/myFlaskAppenv) that is a chatbot and I want the chatbot to handle the message received from the first one.

At the end of [this tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/01/faq-chatbots-the-future-of-information-searching/) one can read that the path was to launch the following command to start the RASA-NLU server by executing the "run_server.bat" script. Load the custom trained model and start listening to port 5000:

```
$ python -m rasa_nlu.server --path projects
```

I tried the following but the terminal tells me that the port is already in use

```
(myFlaskAppenv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp$ python -m rasa_nlu.server --path ~/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp
/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp/myFlaskAppenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
2018-06-04 17:01:20+0100 [-] Log opened.
2018-06-04 17:01:20+0100 [-] Unhandled error in Deferred:
2018-06-04 17:01:20+0100 [-] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp/myFlaskAppenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rasa_nlu/server.py", line 402, in <module>
        rasa.app.run('0.0.0.0', cmdline_args.port)
      File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp/myFlaskAppenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/klein/app.py", line 392, in run
        endpoint.listen(Site(self.resource()))
      File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp/myFlaskAppenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py", line 488, in listen
        interface=self._interface)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp/myFlaskAppenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 121, in execute
        result = callable(*args, **kw)
      File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp/myFlaskAppenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 495, in listenTCP
        p.startListening()
      File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp/myFlaskAppenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 980, in startListening
        raise CannotListenError(self.interface, self.port, le)
    twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on 0.0.0.0:5000: [Errno 98] Address already in use.
```

Indeed :

```
(myFlaskAppenv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp$ python app.py 
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 213-078-895
 * Detected change in '/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp/app.py', reloading
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 213-078-895
```

So, for the moment when I try to talk to the chatbot it gives me that in the terminal lou I put `app.py` that contains all the routes:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2018 16:42:46] "GET /parse?q=hi HTTP/1.1" 404 -
HOUSTON ! WE GOT AN EXCETPITON !
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2018 16:42:46] "POST /chat HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Here is the part of `app.py` that refers to the handling of chatbot messages, tell me if there is more need, but I think it is not the most important:

```
@app.route('/chat',methods=["POST"])
def chat():
    try:
        user_message = request.form["text"]
        response = requests.get("http://localhost:5000/parse",params={"q":user_message})
        response = response.json()
        entities = response.get("entities")
        topresponse = response["topScoringIntent"]
        intent = topresponse.get("intent")
        print("Intent {}, Entities {}".format(intent,entities))
        if intent == "gst-info":
            response_text = gst_info(entities)# "Sorry will get answer soon" #get_event(entities["day"],entities["time"],entities["place"])
        elif intent == "gst-query":
            response_text = gst_query(entities)
        else:
            response_text = get_random_response(intent)
        return jsonify({"status":"success","response":response_text})
    except Exception as e:
        print("HOUSTON ! WE GOT AN EXCETPITON !")
        print(e)
        return jsonify({"status":"success","response":"Sorry I am not trained to do that yet..."})
```

**So, what command should I make for the chatbot server to start listening and discussing with port 5000?**

---

[[image of the chatbot][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1r3gU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1r3gU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just choose the port you want your app to run :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=your_port,debug=True)
```